# Sample of topology distinguishable but not separated.

Tags: general-topology

I'm confused with the definition of $R_0$ space that any two topologically distinguishable points are separated.
Is there a sample of two topologically distinguishable points are not separated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest example of a space like that is a [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), say $X=\{0,1\}$ with topology 
$\{\emptyset, \{0\},X\}$. The two points $0$ and $1$ are topologically distinguishable: their sets of neighbourhoods are different: $\{0\}$ has neighbourhoods $\{0\}$ and $X$, and $1$ has only $X$.

But they cannot be separated as $1$ does *not* have an open neighbourhood that does not contain $0$.

Recall that $x\neq y \in (X, \mathcal{T})$ are topologically distinguishable iff

$$\left(\exists U \in \mathcal{T}: (x \in U \land y \notin U)\right) \lor \left(  \exists U \in \mathcal{T}: (x \notin U \land y \in U) \right)\tag{1}$$

which is a formal way of saying that $\mathcal{O}(x) \neq \mathcal{O}(y)$, where those symbols denote the set of open neighbourhoods of $x$ resp. $y$.

And $x \neq y$ are called separated iff

$$\left(\exists U \in \mathcal{T}: (x \in U \land y \notin U)\right) \land \left(  \exists U \in \mathcal{T}: (x \notin U \land y \in U) \right)\tag{2}$$

So it's clear that (instead of "and" we have "or"):

> "$x$ and $y$ are separated" $\implies$ "$x$ and $y$ are topologically distinguishable" $\implies$ $x \neq y$.

And $X$ is $T_0$ iff we can reverse the last arrow, and $X$ is $R_0$ iff we can reverse the first arrow. 
And a space is $T_1$ iff the first and last statement are equivalent, and so $R_0 + T_0 \iff T_1$. So we will have examples of such points as you aked for in any space that is $T_0$ but not $T_1$, like Sierpiński space.

Slightly more interesting examples: $X=\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ in the upper topology $\{\emptyset, n^\uparrow (n \in \mathbb{N})\}$, where $n^\uparrow=\{m \in \mathbb{N}: m \ge n\}$ and the same $X$ in the lower topology $\{X, \emptyset, n^\downarrow (n \in \Bbb N)\}$, where $n^\downarrow=\{m \in \Bbb N: m \le n\}$. In both spaces, all pairs of distinct points are topologically distinguishable, but no such pair is separated. Fun fact: any infinite $T_0$ space that is not $T_1$ will contain one of these as a subspace, BTW.

As an extreme (non-)example: let $X$ $(|X| \ge 2$) be any set in the indiscrete (trivial) topology: in this $X$ there are *no* points that are topologically indistinguishable (all have $\mathcal{O}(x)=X$) so *voidly* $X$ is $R_0$ (*all pairs* of indistinguishable points can be separated because there are no such pairs).

The example by GreginGre (the double-pointed countably infinite cofinite space) is an example of a different kind: it shows $R_0$ (which this space is) does not imply either $T_0$ nor $T_1$, so the R-axioms (there is also $R_1$) are "independent' of the T-axioms, so to say.

Comment: In your example,can I say that "$0$ can be separated from $1$,but $1$ can not be separated from $0$"?

Comment: @NFDream yes, in principle. But being separated is symmetric:you say $x$ and $y$ are separated if $(2)$ holds and so it’s a property of a *pair* of points.

Comment: @NFDream yes and no, separable is having a countable dense subset. In general, $A$ and $B$ are separated iff $\emptyset = A\cap \overline{B}=\overline{A}\cap B$. Points are separated iff their singleton sets are.

Comment: In the example, $ \overline {\{1\}}  $ is $\{0,1\}$, and $\{0\} \cap \overline {\{1\}}\neq \emptyset$，so they are not separated.

Comment: That's helpful a lot, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The double point cofinite topology seems to be the example you are looking for.

See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Double-pointed_cofinite_topology

Comment: Does the "separated" means there is an open set contain one of the two points precisely or $\overline {\{x\}}\cap \{y\}=\emptyset$ ?

Comment: This is not an example: in this space points are either not topologically distinguishable (the doubles), or already separated. This space is $R_0$ (but neither $T_0$ nor $T_1$).